# Error accessing BuildSystem.AzurePipelines in cakebuild

Tags: c#, azure-devops, cakebuild

Within my cake script I'm trying to access the following, to check if it's running on the master branch:

```cs
var isMasterBranch = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("master",
    BuildSystem.AzurePipelines.Environment.Repository.Branch);
```

however, when I run `dotnet cake` I get the following error

```sh
❯ dotnet cake
/Users/x/Repos/y/build.cake(11,17): error CS1061: 'BuildSystem' does not contain a definition for 'AzurePipelines' and no accessible extension method 'AzurePipelines' accepting a first argument of type 'BuildSystem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The cake version in pinned to 0.38.5 inside the `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Cake" version="0.38.5" />
</packages>
xml
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Cake are you running?

The `AzurePipelines` alias was introduced in version 0.38.0. In previous versions you need to use `TFBuild`.

Comment: It's pinned to `0.38.5`, not sure what's going off.

Comment: @KevinSmith Can you share the build script or the task where you make the call to `BuildSystem.AzurePipelines`?

Comment: dotnet cake won't use the package config though, it uses Cake.Tool which is another nuget package bootstrapped through .NET CLI

Comment: See [Runners](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/runners/) for an overview of the different runners and [Pinning Cake Version](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/reproducible-builds/pinning-cake-version) how to pin to a specific version for every runner.

Comment: @devlead that's it! It was the wrong version but I was looking in the wrong place. That one is set to `0.27.0`